# Debugging slow Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

We are using K8S in a managed Azure environment, Minikube in Ubuntu and a Rancher cluster built on on-prem machines and in general, our deployments take up to about 30 seconds to pull containers, run up and be ready. However, my latest attempt to create a deployment (on-prem) takes upwards of a minute and sometimes longer. It is a small web service which is very similar to our other deployments. The only (obvious) difference is the use of a startup probe and a liveness probe, although some of our other services do have probes, they are different though.

After removing Octopus deploy from the equation by extracting the yaml it was running and using kubectl, as soon as the (single) pod starts, I start reading the logs and as expected, the startup and liveness probes are called very quickly. Startup succeeds and the cluster starts calling the live probe, which also succeeds. However, if I use `kubectl describe` on the pod, it shows Initialized and PodScheduled as True but ContainersReady (there is one container) and Ready are both false for around a minute. I can't see what would cause this other than probe failures but these are logged as successful.

They eventually start and work OK but I don't know why they take so long.

```yaml
kind: Deployment 
apiVersion: apps/v1 
metadata: 
  name: 'redirect-files-deployments-28775' 
  labels: 
    Octopus.Kubernetes.SelectionStrategyVersion: "SelectionStrategyVersion2" 
    OtherOctopusLabels
spec: 
  replicas: 1 
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      Octopus.Kubernetes.DeploymentName: 'redirect-files-deployments-28775' 

  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        Octopus.Kubernetes.SelectionStrategyVersion: "SelectionStrategyVersion2" 
        OtherOctopusLabels

    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: redirect-files 
        image: ourregistry.azurecr.io/microservices.redirectfiles:1.0.34 
        ports: 
        - name: http 
          containerPort: 80 
          protocol: TCP 
        env: 
        - removed connection strings etc
        livenessProbe: 
          httpGet: 
            path: /api/version 
            port: 80 
            scheme: HTTP 
          successThreshold: 1 
        startupProbe: 
          httpGet: 
            path: /healthcheck 
            port: 80 
            scheme: HTTP 
            httpHeaders: 
            - name: X-SS-Authorisation 
              value: asdkjlkwe098sad0akkrweklkrew 

          initialDelaySeconds: 5 
          timeoutSeconds: 5 
      imagePullSecrets: 
      - name: octopus-feedcred-feeds-azure-container-registry
```

Comment: Have you checked your Pod definition? Are you sure there aren't any LimitRange, that may set some resource limits/requests you wouldn't know of? And/or: have you tried setting resource limits/requests, making sure the scheduler would assign your Deployment to a Node that has enough resources?

Comment: @syn. No. We only have a small cluster with 4 equal size nodes that has plenty of capacity for the small number of pods that are currently running. While the pods are slow, the CPU on the node is very low according to the hypervisor and the service doesn't do anything special, it just starts up a dotnet core web service.

Comment: It's hard to tell ... if you're certain there were no limits/requests automatically added on top of your pod template, ... have you tried starting several replicas/any chance app won't use more than one CPU? When you say it's slow: compared to what? Pod being in ContainerCreating means that it's initializing, pulling images, mounting volumes, ... first suspect would be a large image and/or I/Os limited volumes. Comparing startup times between k8s on VMs and docker on a dev laptop isn't really relevant. You're nesting container+virt techs, with network drives (SDS), two layers of SDN, ... .

Comment: Thanks @SYN. There are no volumes for this container and the images are only a few hundred meg (alpine + an app) and since the probes are called very soon after creation, it must be something that happens after the containers are created although I would still expect them to be shown as ContainersReady. When I say slow, the hicharts deployment to the same cluster (similar size) takes 20 seconds. The only thing I can think of is to strip everything out one by one and see if adding them in shows me.

Comment: Although if there was some deployment log showing what is happening against a timeline, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the cause was the startup and/or liveness probes. When I removed them, the deployment time went from over a minute to 18 seconds, despite the logs proving that the probes were called successfully very quickly after containers were started.

At least I now have something more concrete to look for.

Comment: This must be why Azure ML deployments take so long too.